# Configuring `TeXMaker` to work with the `TeXLive` distribution

Tags: texmaker

Using `TeXMaker` as the `LaTeX` editor I have been working with the `MikTeX` distribution for a number of years, successfully. Hearing it suggested that `Tex Live` may have a compilation speed advantage over `MikTeX`, I recently installed `TexLive` to see for myself, expecting that configuring `TeXMaker` to work with `TeXLive` in place of `MiKTeX` would be an easy thing. The `Options` menu offers `Configure TeXMaker` tab which provides fields `LaTeX` and `PdfLaTeX` presumably to be populated with the programs to be executed for `LaTeX` and `PDFLaTeX` compilations (function keys f2 and f6 respectively). Having found executables `pdflatex.exe` in `C:/Users/Reinhard Neuwirth/AppData/Local/Programs/MikTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/X64` (my routinely used `MikTeX` distribution) as well as in `C:/texlive/2018/bin/win32/` (the recently installed `TeXLive` distribution) I naively assumed that plugging either one or the other into the `PDFLaTeX` field would coerce `TeXMaker` to use the targeted distribution for compilation. Not so. The only entry in that field that seems to work is `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode \%.tex`, seemingly the default value - for the `LaTeX` field it is `latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.

The extensive discussion around the topic on the Stack Exchange, starting with `Using MiKTeX and TeX Live on the same computer? asked Oct 11 '11 at 11:56 doncherry ... answered Oct 11 '11 at 12:21 Ulrike Fischer` veers off into discussions of how to set `PATHS` in `Windows` etc., a place I don't want to go. Also, I am not at this stage interested in switching between `MikTeX` or `TeXLive`, just want to know how to configure `TeXMaker` to do one or the other through the `Configure TeXMaker` tab, if this can be done.

No `MWE` for this one.

Comment: Not tested, but maybe you could make use of `Options --> configure TeXMaker --> Add to PATH`.

Comment: Looks like a possibility, but have not been able to make it perform as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to switch the texsystem you *must* change the path variable. The texsystems often call their tools themselves (e.g. to create a format or a tfm or search for files) and so must be able to find their own binaries. Simply trying to use `C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe` while everything else (including the kpathsea searches) points to miktex gives only chaos.

I don't know if texmaker has an option to change the path during a session -- with my editor winedt it is quite easy to do it on-the-fly by calling a macro.

But you can change the path to texlive between sessions rather easily:

Open a `cmd` window. Type

```
  set PATH=C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32;%PATH%
```

hit enter. Test if the correct pdflatex is found by typing

```
  where pdflatex
```

and then start texmaker *from this cmd window* by typing in the path to the texmaker exe.

If something doesn't work, simply close texmaker and the `cmd` window and the path will be back to normal.

Comment: My current situation is that typing at the Command Prompt either `set PATH=C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe;%PATH%` or `set PATH=C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32;%PATH%` will result in  `C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth>where pdflatex  
C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe  
C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe`. The response suggests that PATH is loaded with texlive **and** miktex. I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: … further, on the odd occasion `where pdflatex` produces the Windows operating system response `'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: if doesn't matter if both are in the path, the one found first is important.

Comment: All works as it should now!